# Storing and retrieving data from server host using Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I have an assignment where I have to build a Client-Server communication using Java. So what I did was building a Client-Server connect using Sockets, the following way:

```
         //Client code
         Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4999);
```

```
        //Server code
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4999);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Client is connected");
```

For now, the communication between the client and the server is successful, I am able to send messages from client to server and vice versa. but the main problem is storing data on the server host, we were asked to store relevant data on the server host so the server could send it to the client.
Can someone please explain to me how to store data on the server and how to retrieve it ??
Thanks

Comment: You can create some objects in memory, use databases (SQL or no-SQL), write and read files (locally or using cloud services such Amazon S3).  Your question is a bit broad, please try to make it more focused.

Answer (score 0):

To read from the server socket:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket socket = server.accept();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
//Do whatever you want with the DataInputStream
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-inputstream-server-socket

Then we can move to the input stream processing, here is a sample:

```
...
int i;
char c;
...

try{

 // reads till the end of the stream
         while((i = in .read())!=-1) {
         
            // converts integer to character
            c = (char)i;
            
            // prints character
            System.out.print(c);
         }

} catch(Exception e){
   //Handle....
} finally {
   // Close stream...
}
```

Source: [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read.htm#:~:text=io.-,InputStream.,the%20returned%20value%20is%20%2D1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read.htm#:%7E:text=io.-,InputStream.,the%20returned%20value%20is%20%2D1).

For writing to the socket (the response to the client), just follow the following tutorial, no need to repeat it here:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-write-a-server-socket-that-can-handle-input-and-output.html

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for answering, my question might have been not as clear, my point was asking how could I retrieve data stored on the server host.